# SQLiteManager from SQLabs - Why isn't my database recognized by iOS app

Tags: ios, sqlite

I created a SQLite DB in the `SQLiteManager` from SQLabs and then added the DB file mydb.sqlite3 to an iOS SDK app that I built.  I believe I have correctly configured the app to use SQLite as I can (in code) create a DB, create a table and query it.

When I drag my externally created DB into the app folder it appears in a Group underneath the app. It also appears in the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase of the app.

When I try to query the externally created DB.  I get an error that the table was not found, I'm assuming that this is because the db file is somehow not being included in the build and when I open the database it by default creates one.

To confirm this thought, if I uninstall the app from the simulator and run the app again in the debugger, this time containing (before I open the db) some debug code to `NSLog()` all files in the application, the database file is not listed in the log.

Any thoughts on why a DB that is included in the project would not get copied into the app documents folder on the simulator when I run the debugger?

Comment: 2 questions: are you using Core Data? and the second: did you copy the file from the bundle to the Documents folder in your code?

Comment: I'm not using core data.  I did not copy the file from the bundle to the docs folder in code and wasn't aware of the need to do that

Comment: If you open the simulator app in Finder you can see all the files in the simulated file system.  From there you can use an OSx SQLite tool to look at the DB.  But of course, you must first copy the DB out of the bundle and into the simulated file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to:

1) Check that the database does not already exist
2) Copy the database from the main bundle to the documents folder

```
NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[self MR_applicationDocumentsDirectory]];
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

for (NSString *path in paths) 
{
    NSString *filepath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:storeFileName];
    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:filepath])
    {

    } else {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourDBNameHere" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [fm copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:filepath error:NULL];
        }

     }
}
```